Asus Command USBLock Forgotten Password
I used to use an Asus pc, and there is a preinstalled program called Asus Command on the pc. In the program, there is a feature called USBLock, which allows you to lock the USB ports for data transfer. For some stupid security reasons, I set a password to lock/unlock USB ports for data transfer. Then I stopped using the pc for two years, and now I have no idea what the password is. The program doesn't have any anti-bruteforce features, so I am able to try as many passwords as I want (gosh I have tried so many). I am kinda of scared to delete the program cause I have no idea whether this solves the problem or completely destroys my chance of solving it. Finally, I gave up trying and said why not write a Python script which brute forces a password list that I have created. I know it's a bit overkill, but I would really want to improve my python knowledge with this kind of project. I tried using pyautogui, but it seems like it doesn't work inside of the Asus Command. Does anybody know how to turn off the USBLock? or maybe any ideas/library recommendations for automating a task like this on Windows?


Do the USB ports work normally when you boot something other than your full OS? Like a live Linux or Windows Recovery?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

See https://www.asus.com/support/faq/1050827/ for ASUS toool. Also, as @KamilMaciorowski implies, this lock could be implemented inf firmware or in the operating system. If you boot from USB and can access USB ports, then it's implemented in the OS. If the ports are still locked, though, there might need to be changes made to firmware through BIOS or otherwise -- you'll need the ASUS app to fix that, likely.

Download a Windows 11 VM from Microsoft.  Do the USB ports work within the VM?

I tried to live boot parrotOS with a USB drive but the pc only boots up windows and It also doesn't enter BIOS. I tried every key, checked the manual, and even tried turning off the fast boot option. None of them worked so right now I'll try to create a virtual machine and plug in a USB drive to check whether that works.

How exactly have turned off "Fast Boot" if it doesn't "enter BIOS"? For reference: Fast Boot is a firmware (UEFI) feature and can only be enabled/disabled in the UEFI ("BIOS") settings. It won't make any difference anyway. Nor disabling "Fast Startup", a Windows feature, that likely you're confusing with "Fast Boot".  Now, how EXACTLY can't you enter UEFI settings? Is it password protected?

My bad, I meant fast startup. I am not sure why I cannot enter BIOS. It is not password protected. It just instantly boots up windows no matter what I do. Before USBLock I was able to enter It without any problems.

It should be the exact same way as before unless as commented/asked above, the tool locked the firmware as well. That being the case you can reset it but all your personal data will be gone for good: https://www.asus.com/support/faq/1046347/ (it seems unrelated but then it is related)

Since data transfer doesn't work I cannot backup any of my files to a USB drive so either I will upload it to the cloud or I will try to brute force the password :(
